# added aurelia-validation and getting BindingLanguage must implement inspectTextContent()

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm trying to add validation to a cli generated TypeScript-Project and keep getting " BindingLanguage must implement inspectTextContent()" as soon as I add .plugin("aurelia-validation").

On my Win10 Machine it's reproducable with the following steps:

- au new test [Web, TypeScript, None(Style), Yes(test),VSCode]
- npm install aurelia-validation --save
- add the dependency in aurelia.json
- and then add aurelia.use.plugin("aurelia-validation") in main.ts

Full error from chrome console:
Unhandled rejection Error: BindingLanguage must implement inspectTextContent().
    at mi (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19678:11)
    at BindingLanguage.inspectTextContent (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19695:7)
    at ViewCompiler._compileNode (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:21481:79)
    at ViewCompiler._compileNode (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:21501:33)
    at ViewCompiler.compile (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:21448:12)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:22106:50
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:22099:119
From previous event:
    at ViewEngine.loadViewFactory (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:22083:67)
    at ConventionalViewStrategy.loadViewFactory (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19503:25)
    at HtmlBehaviorResource.load (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:22841:29)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23374:18
From previous event:
    at CompositionEngine.createController (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23362:71)
    at CompositionEngine._createControllerAndSwap (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23341:19)
    at CompositionEngine.compose (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23421:21)
    at TemplatingEngine.compose (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23689:38)
    at Aurelia.setRoot (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:12528:21)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/app-bundle.js:53:59
From previous event:
    at Object.configure (http://localhost:9000/scripts/app-bundle.js:53:25)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11382:22
From previous event:
    at config (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11377:48)
    at handleApp (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11368:12)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11401:13
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11399:40
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11398:29
From previous event:
    at run (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11394:26)
    at Object. (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11421:3)
    at Object.execCb (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5449:33)
    at Module.check (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4637:51)
    at Module.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4929:22)
    at Object.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5310:39)
    at Module. (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4914:33)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3890:23
    at each (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3815:31)
    at Module.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4866:17)
    at Module.init (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:4542:26)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5213:36